# Jackson - Return Date object as Long representation

Tags: java, json, date, spring-mvc, jackson

I was using Jackson 1.x and Spring-MVC and had a whole set-up where dates were sent as their long representation (default behavior) and then via JavaScript formatted the given long as desired. The problem I have is that since I switched to Jackson 2.x, dates are being sent as `String`s in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

How can I configure Jackson so it defaults to send dates as `Long`s?

Update:
The versions:
- Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE
- Jackson 2.3.3

All my dates are `java.util.Date` objects.

Comment: Which exact version of Jackson and Spring exactly are you using?

Comment: Make sure your dates aren't actually instances of java.sql.Date (which extends java.util.Date).

Comment: Agreed, otherwise Jackson2 by default serializes dates as epoch. 
read more here http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling